# liquibase database build from scratch

Tags: mysql, liquibase

When I run liquibase update from scratch, it takes a while as the process fires each changelog one by one. Sometimes my own database changes diverge enough that its easiest to rebuild the database if I want to start again for example.

The rebuild would be quickest if I did it from a mysql dump of the result of liquibase at a certain point in the changelogs, and I ignored the changelogs from there previously. So I would delete everything in changelog master except my master build dump changelog, which would be the entire database, and I keep hold of the actual changelogs for version control reasons.

Is there a proper/ordained/safe way to do this from liquibase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no standard way to "restart" a changelog file because your environment and setup can greatly affect what works best for you.

Often times the easiest approach is to not completely restart your changelog file but instead make modifications to it. Databases are generally fast at DDL, especially on an empty database and so often times what makes a clean database rebuild is a small portion of the changeSets. Re-defining indexes are often a big part of the problem, but other things can be as well. Watch what changeSets take a log time and perhaps you can find some that cancel each other out or are now unneeded but still take up a bulk of the time.

If it will work best for you to start from scratch, the process is basically the same as starting to use Liquibase on an existing project. See the documentation at http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/existing_project.html for ideas on options with this.

With mysql one option may be to use mysqldump and then have a single changeSet using `<execute>` to call the mysql restore shell command.

As for your existing databasechangelog rows, Liquibase uses the path as part of the changeSet identifier and so if your new changelog file has a different name or path Liquibase will already see the changeSets as new. Alternately, you could start your new changelog file with a `<changeSet>` that does a `delete from databasechangelog`